# Updated MoPub and now I get "can't find referenced field" for ExoPlayer when building the signed apk

Tags: android, proguard, exoplayer, mopub, exoplayer2.x

The latest MoPub SDK (5.3) I guess updated the version of ExoPlayer. My app also uses ExoPlayer. I'm getting now the warning below when generating the signed apk. If I add a `dontwarn` to proguard then my code fails because it can't find those fields at runtime.

I have this on my proguard and this has been working for a long while, it only started failing after updating MoPub today.

```
-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer2.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.exoplayer2.**{ *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.exoplayer2.** { *; }
```

This is the error:

```
Warning: MyClass: can't find referenced field 'int mediaSequence' in program class com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsMediaPlaylist
Warning: MyClass: can't find referenced field 'boolean isEncrypted' in program class com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsMediaPlaylist$Segment
Warning: MyClass: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String encryptionKeyUri' in program class com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsMediaPlaylist$Segment
```

What can I do to get around this error?

UPDATE: The field are defined like this:

```
public final int mediaSequence;
public final boolean isEncrypted;
public final String encryptionKeyUri;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was compiling an old version of ExoPlayer and MoPub somehow was including a new one but only for a small part of it, the HLS part. This appears to have caused the issue because once I started compiling the new one on my own code everything started working again. It was very strange as the new version even made me change the code a bit so I have no idea how it was even compiling before.